# compare two dfs and delete duplicates from second

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a one df generate weekly, what I want to do is compare it with another dataframe and delete duplicates from newly generated one.
I have tried this:

```
            #adding master column to old df
            df['master'] = 'master'
            df.set_index('master', append=True, inplace=True)
            #dropping duplicates from new df
            new_df.drop_duplicates( keep=False, inplace=True)
            #adding daily column to newly generated df
            new_df['daily'] = 'daily'
            new_df.set_index('daily', append=True, inplace=True)
            #merging both dfs
            merged = df.append(new_df)
            #droping duplicates from merged df
            merged = merged.drop_duplicates().sort_index()
            #updating new df with updated df with no duplicates
            idx = pd.IndexSlice
            new_df = merged.loc[idx[:, 'daily'], :]
```

but this is not working as expected and is not deleting duplicates

Comment: Are you considering entire row as duplicate?

Comment: Is it not dropping them because your rows are not exactly identical? If you are just trying to drop them based on duplicates in a specific column, then you need to add the [subset parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) (e.g. `subset=["Column_Name"]`)

Comment: @Srikanth yes i consider whole row as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you are rows are not identical, then you need to set the column names in the subset. Also you can use keep to keep the first, last etc..

E.g.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand', 'style'], keep='last')
```